# Automate the removal of git-rebase-mode and git-commit-mode

Tags: package, magit, emacs24

From the Magit docs:

> Furthermore the old dependencies `git-commit-mode` and `git-rebase-mode` have to be removed because they are no longer used by the `2.1.0` release and later, and get in the way of their successors `git-commit` and `git-rebase`.

I have a lot of machines that have these old packages lying around. Is there any way I can teach `magit` to automatically clean them up?

Answer (score 1):

This should be your package manager's duty, not magit, if you are using `package.el` on Emacs 25, you can try `package-autoremove`. From `C-h f package-autoremove`:

> (package-autoremove)
>
> Remove packages that are no more needed.
>
> Packages that are no more needed by other packages in
>   ‘package-selected-packages’ and their dependencies will be deleted.

There is a post from Artur Malabarba on this: http://endlessparentheses.com/new-in-package-el-in-emacs-25-1-better-dependency-management.html

Comment: I'm not saying it's `magit`'s job, just that I want the packages to be removed automatically somehow. Emacs 25 is, unfortunately not an option. There are Debian boxes running `24.4`.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541322/how-to-remove-installed-elpa-package suggests simply removing the package directories from your disk.

`package-delete` is undocumented in Emacs 24, but seems to do the same thing (as well as removing any `.signed` file corresponding to the deleted package).